# Split text file every 120,000 Lines?

Tags: c#, .net, text

So I have a textfile I need to split every 120,000, when it's split at the 120,000th line I need the rest to into another text file. Any ideas on this guys?

Comment: yeah very easy. read line by line and hold a counter when the counter is that number, write to new file.

Comment: What have you done so far? Present your code, then we can help :)

Comment: Use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) and a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another way using `Enumerable.GroupBy` and "integer division groups":

```
int batchSize = 120000;
var fileGroups = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select((line, index) => new { line, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / batchSize)
    .Select((group, index) => new {
        Path = Path.Combine(dir, string.Format("FileName_{0}.txt", index + 1)),
        Lines = group.Select(x => x.line)
    });
foreach (var file in fileGroups)
    File.WriteAllLines(file.Path, file.Lines);
```

Comment: and the readability is through the roof! :) I actually thought of a similar answer using Select and GroupBy and a Func<> for the filename, tucked away in a method - but it's just.. so.. hideous.. :s It really does not show of the pretty side of LINQ (which Servys answer kind of hides away at least). BTW.. another reason I did not post was that I was not sure of the performance boost. Servys answer loads 12000 entities at the time (via the bucket) - Do you know if this is better since it's all IEnumerables and IGroupings (and yields I guess), i.e. would it perform better?

Comment: @Default: You're dead right! LINQ is often not the right tool if the index comes into play. I've shown the approach only 1. it's relatively short, 2. doesn't need a third party library/code and 3. the more often you use it the more readable it seems to be ;)

Comment: @Default: acc. to the performance, i assume that morelinq is more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Batch from MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) to group your lines into batches of 120,000 lines, which can then each be handles separately.

```
foreach(var batch in File.ReadLines(inputFile).Batch(120000))
    WriteToFile(batch);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var lines = new List<string>();
int counter = 0,i = 1;
string line;
using (var reader = new StreamReader("filePath"))
{
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
          lines.Add(line);
          counter++;
          if (counter == 120000)
          {
              string fileName = String.Format("file{0}.txt",i);
              File.WriteAllLines(fileName,lines);
              lines.Clear();
              counter = 0;
              i++;
          }
    }
}
if(lines.Count > 0) File.WriteAllLines("path", lines);
```

Note: You should use different file names when using the `File.WriteAllLines`, otherwise you will just overwrite a single file's content.For example you can use another counter for it and increment it for every file, `"file1, file2 etc.."`.

Comment: -1, would end up writing to same file again and again

Comment: @NewHire OP should change the file path.Obviously he can figure out that right (at least!)?

Comment: @NewHire, this can easily be fixed, IMHO shouldn't be a downvote.

Comment: Any reason using a `StreamReader` instead of the `File.ReadLines` method?

Comment: @Default it can be used but not necessary.`File.ReadLines`  still using `StreamReader` though...I find this way more straightforward

Comment: yeah, you're not the first one I see using it actually, which made me wonder.. I guess the same could be said about `File.WriteAllLines` then (why not use `StreamWriter`) :)

Comment: @Selman22 Using a `StreamReader` directly takes a lot more code, which means more time to write, it increases the probability of a mistake, decreases readability (pretty dramatically in my opinion), and doesn't allow the use of LINQ operators on the sequence.